# Vue.js и jQuery маски для полей

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

Господа, знаю JS очень поверхностно, задача следующая, нужно сделать маски для полей на странице регистрации (дата и телефон). Я подключил js скрипт для масок и добавляю в основной скрипт следующие:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.date').mask('00/00/0000', {placeholder: "__/__/____"});
$('.phone').mask('+0 (000) 000 00 00', {placeholder: "+_ (___) ___ __ __"});


});
```

Плейсхолдер появляется, но сами маски не применяются (можно вводить буквы), если убрать из формы директивы "v-model: phone" и "v-model: birthday" то маски отрабатывают как нужно, но данные не отправляются, точнее не проходят валидацию.

JS файл:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.date').mask('00/00/0000', {placeholder: "__/__/____"});
$('.phone').mask('+0 (000) 000 00 00', {placeholder: "+_ (___) ___ __ __"});


});

(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        stm_lms_register_custom(true);
    })
})(jQuery);
function stm_lms_register_custom(redirect) {
    var vue_obj = {
        el: '#stm-lms-register-custom',
        data: function () {
            return {
                vue_loaded: true,
                loading: false,
                login: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                password_re: '',
                birthday: '',
                phone: '',
                message: '',
                status: '',
                site_key: '',
                become_instructor: '',
                degree: '',
                expertize: '',
                recaptcha: '',
                captcha_error: '',
                privacy_policy: true,
                has_privacy_policy: false,
                choose_auditory : false,
                auditory : '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            hasPrivacyPolicy() {
                if (!this.has_privacy_policy) {
                    this.has_privacy_policy = true;
                    this.privacy_policy = false;
                }
            },
            register() {
                var vm = this;
                vm.loading = true;
                vm.message = '';

                var data = {
                    'user_login': vm.login,
                    'user_email': vm.email,
                    'user_password': vm.password,
                    'user_password_re': vm.password_re,
                    'user_birthday': vm.birthday,
                    'user_phone': vm.phone,
                    'become_instructor': vm.become_instructor,
                    'privacy_policy': vm.privacy_policy,
                    'degree': vm.degree,
                    'expertize': vm.expertize,
                    'auditory' : vm.auditory
                };

                if (vm.site_key) {
                    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                        grecaptcha.execute(vm.site_key, {action: 'register'}).then(function (token) {
                            data['recaptcha'] = token;
                            vm.processRegister(data);
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    vm.processRegister(data);
                }
            },
            processRegister(data) {

                var vm = this;
                vm.$http.post(stm_lms_ajaxurl + '?action=stm_lms_register&nonce=' + stm_lms_nonces['stm_lms_register_custom'], data).then(function (response) {
                    vm.message = response.body['message'];
                    vm.status = response.body['status'];
                    vm.loading = false;

                    if (response.body['user_page']) {
                        if (redirect) {
                            window.location = response.body['user_page'];
                        } else {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    };
    new Vue(vue_obj);
}
```

Фрагмент формы:

```
                <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="heading_font"><?php esc_html_e('Date of Birth', 'masterstudy-child'); ?></label><b class="obligatory"> *</b>
                <input class="form-control date"
                       type="text"
                       data-mask="00/00/0000"
                       name="birthday"
                       v-model="birthday"
                      />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="heading_font"><?php esc_html_e('Phone Number', 'masterstudy-child'); ?></label>
                <input class="form-control phone"
                       type="text"
                       name="phone"
                       v-model="phone"
                       placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Phone Number', 'masterstudy-child'); ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Думаю, что проблема в прямом изменении DOM с помощью jQuery, т.к. у Vue свое управление через Virtual DOM. Може быть стоит найти плагин к Vue для этих целей?

Comment: @t0lik, да, гуглил, нашёл несколько. Проблема в том, что я сам JS очень слабо знаю, не говоря уже про Vue, поэтому меня несколько запутало даже само описания процесса установки плагина

Comment: Я не рекомендую смешивать jQuery-плагины или компоненты с VueJs либо они они должны быть протестированы в нем ранее кем-то (разработчик это указал, к примеру).

Comment: @t0lik согласен, проблема в том, что это сделано в одном вордпрессовском плагине, там очень непонятно подключен этот вью.джс, поэтому у меня даже не получается прикрутить к нему плагин для масок

Comment: тогда совегую добавить тэг про вордпресс и плагин, возможно кто-то знает как быть